# YouTube IFrame Player API doesn't fire onReady event in IE if run in a local environment

Tags: internet-explorer, postmessage, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to implement the recommended YouTube IFrame Player API.

The problem I have is that the API doesn't fire the onReady event in IE if it is run locally. Interestingly, the problem does not exist in either Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.

I searched this site, and found a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/LV49fIR5Uo0) where Jeff Posnick, a member of the YouTube API Team, explains that:

> There are a number of security restrictions that prevent http: and 
>   file: resources from talking to each other, both in the postMessage() 
>   JavaScript calls and in the Flash runtime.

Does anybody know what kind of security restrictions Mr Posnick write about, and why are they limited to IE only?

P.S: Even more interesting, I have just tried [Vimeo Player API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js), which also uses iframes and postMessage(), and it does work in IE if run locally.

Comment: IE has a lot of settings hidden in its “Internet Options” that influence this kind of stuff. // Is this an out-of-interest kind of question, or is there an actual problem to solve here? (Because I don’t assume you will be running the end result of your efforts “locally” as well, or do you?)

Comment: @CBroe It is the actual problem. A script employing YouTube API is loaded from a disk into a TWebBrowser. This is the basis of the incremental video feature available in a speed-learning program SuperMemo. The old JavaScript API stopped working on Aug 11 so I decided to upgrade it to the latest IFrame API but hit the above snag. What's interesting, Vimeo Player API which is based on the same technology (iframe and postMessage()) does not have this problem, which leads me to believe it belongs to YouTube competencies than Microsoft's

Comment: @Miko: Did you find any solution for this problem? I'm facing the same too. YouTube Iframe doesn't work locally over files:// access.